# Why dotnet doesn't recognizes this as a controller?

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

I started out with dotnet and I immediately run into this issue. I made a simple controller whit a GET which should return a string. However every single time it just throws a 404. I have rewritten this idk how many times at this point and still the same result. Seems as if dotnet does not even recognizes or registers my class as a controller.

Here is the example controller provided by the default VS project and this one works like butter:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace RPG.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my controller which does not work:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace RPG.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("dungeon")]
    public class DungeonController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
            string[] a = { "spider" };
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The same thing worked when I was using dotnet CLI. What is the difference??

Comment: how are you trying to access it ? _(the url you use)_

Comment: @gepa The same way as in the example: 
`https://localhost:44449/weatherforecast`
`https://localhost:44449/dungeon`
I have tried may different ways ("/api/.." and such and still didn't work)(I have even rewrote the mapping in `Program.cs` many times

Comment: You seem to be approaching this from a standpoint that it can't find your controller. I'm sure that the DI system and MVC are perfectly aware of your controller. More than likely, you just haven't set up your routing correctly for the URL you want to use. One thing I like to do with my API is add [Swagger via Swashbuckle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) so it will generate a nice UI at /swagger. It will show all the controller endpoints and the URLs used to reach them.

Comment: @mason it works in swagger as expected

Answer (score -1):

The proxy config was not set up correctly on the frontend.

Comment: What proxy config?

Comment: Angular proxy config. I forgot about that because I am used to having my own config which lets me proxy every request.

Comment: You should delete the entire question then, as leaving out some entire component from the question means no one else would have been able to answer this or will benefit from this.